# Error configuring postgresql and sqlitedb3

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

Iam working on a django project and I am  configuring preconfigured database in sqlite3 to postgress locally .First i have done all my migrations to sqlite3 database all was working fine ..
After that i want to migrate to postgressql so i created a local database and connected to it ...
The model iam migrating is ::

```
class State(models.Model):
    statename = models.CharField(db_column='statename',max_length=26,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.statename


class College(models.Model):

    statename= models.ForeignKey(State,db_column='statename',on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='statename')#used to_field to convert int to text must set unique to true for operation
    collegename = models.CharField(db_column='collegename',max_length=30,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.collegename
```

This are the two databases DDL generated by Django  ::
sqlite3 working fine -----

```
CREATE TABLE api_state
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    statename varchar(25) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sqlite_autoindex_api_state_1 ON api_state 
(statename);
CREATE TABLE api_college
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    collegename varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    state varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (state) REFERENCES api_state (statename)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sqlite_autoindex_api_college_1 ON api_college (collegename);
CREATE INDEX api_college_9ed39e2e ON api_college (state)
```

postgress ddl changed after generation with Django::

```
    create table api_college
(
    id serial not null
        constraint api_college_pkey
            primary key,
    collegename varchar(30) not null,
    statename_id integer not null
)
;

create index api_college_b291eb83
    on api_college (statename_id)
;

create table api_state
(
    id serial not null
        constraint api_state_pkey
            primary key,
    statename varchar(25) not null
)
;

alter table api_college
    add constraint api_college_statename_id_7e126c2d_fk_api_state_id
        foreign key (statename_id) references api_state
            deferrable initially deferred
;
```

Error that iam getting int he postgress migration ::

```
File "/home/hexnor/apienv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/hexnor/apienv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(3)
```

Error that i got after confguring postgress database and access django admin on browser::
i have first added state UP
then when iam choosing state as Up and adding college as testcollege iam getting this error ::

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column "statename" of relation "api_college" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "api_college" ("statename", "collegename") VALUE...
```

Comment: The error *value too long for type character varying(3)* doesn't match your PostgreSQL table. Is that a typo? FWIW, SQLite will let you store 30 characters in a 25-character column unless you use a CHECK() constraint.

Comment: Sir the Problem is Foreignkey statename in the model College is returning the statename_id but what I am requiring in postgres is statename ,,,the same project when migrated to sqlite works fine  with returning the statename but when i am migrating to postgres it is causing error as the foreign key field is returning integer,,,,,